# Android CollapsingToolbarLayout lose title

Tags: android

Hi in my android app I'm using a CollapsingToolbarLayout.
[image: Title ok]

I've got this problem: the title is no longer visible when I do the following steps

1. I scroll down the page --> the toolbar got collapsed
2. I move to another activity (settings for example)
3. I get back to the main

The result is the below:

[image: Title ko]

The title is no longer visibile! Debugging I noticed that the Toolbar contains the value but it doesn't show it. Furthermore if I scroll up, move to another activity and get back, the title is visible!

Any advice? It's a nightmare!

Comment: add you're code here for debugging.

Comment: i wonder if your problem was solved, if yes could you please turn your question as resolved

Comment: @cq5beginner, did you solve this problem? I'm dealing with the same issue in Support Library v23.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are facing with an android bug that was fixed in Support Library v23.1.0, so you should try to upgrade your library

hope this was helful ! good luck